# How to update apps outside the US?

Tags: macbook-pro, software-update

I bought my macbook pro in HK and I live in China.
As a new user, I don't understand why I can't update my apps and I see this message:
"Your Apple ID is not valid for use in the Chinese Store. To create a new Apple ID, you must switch to the U.S. Store."

What am I supposed to do? Apple is really weird with these "border limits" in a global world. Please help!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any particular experience with overseas connectivity but I wonder if getting a VPN service specifically from Hong Kong with an exit there would fix the issue. This might allow the HK Apple store to see your MacBook as local to HK rather than where you actually are and connect you to the HK Apple store. I know people do this all the time to connect to TV streams overseas from their home country, might this work the same?

Comment: Thanks Steve. The thing is in order to update the apps, you need an account linked with a bank card that should be from the country you're in. So I created a new account with my Chinese information and tada! it worked. However, I can't use my main email address as ID as it's already in use with my previous account presumably in the US. Is there a way to close this first account in order to "free" my email? Right now I'm using a backup email and I'd rather use my original one.

Comment: That may be one of those times you call Apple Customer service. However someone else might know a link that would lead you thru that process. Sorry, best I can do.

Comment: Thanks Steve, I hope they can be of some help. We'll see about that.

Answer (score -1):

Try going to Settings > iTunes & App Stores > Apple ID > View Apple ID > Country/Region.

Comment: Sorry I don't see this. I've opened App Store App and all I see in the menu is:
App Store, Edit, Store, Window, Help.

Btw, my OS is Yosemite.

Comment: And in System Preferences there is only AppStore and that does not have Apple ID